# What is the most clean & efficient way of joining two tables (dataframes) in R?

Tags: r, merge, vlookup

I'm trying to find out the most efficient way of joining data from one dataframe into another. The idea is that I have a master data set (df) and a secondary dataset (lookup). I want to append the the data in the lookup table to the master data set.

Theoretical data as follows:

```
COLUMN_A <- 1:5
COLUMN_B <- 1:5
LOOKUP_COL <- letters[1:5]


df <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,LOOKUP_COL) 

  COLUMN_A COLUMN_B LOOKUP_COL
1        1        1          a
2        2        2          b
3        3        3          c
4        4        4          d
5        5        5          e

COLUMN_A <- 2*(1:5)
LOOKUP_COL <- letters[1:5]
SPARE_COL <- runif(5)

lookup <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,LOOKUP_COL,SPARE_COL) 

  COLUMN_A LOOKUP_COL SPARE_COL
1        1          a 0.6113499
2        2          b 0.3712987
3        3          c 0.3551038
4        4          d 0.6650248
5        5          e 0.2680611
```

This is how I've been doing it so far:

```
results <- merge(df,lookup,by='LOOKUP_COL')
```

Which provides me with:

```
  LOOKUP_COL COLUMN_A.x COLUMN_B COLUMN_A.y SPARE_COL
1          a          1        1          1 0.6113499
2          b          2        2          2 0.3712987
3          c          3        3          3 0.3551038
4          d          4        4          4 0.6650248
5          e          5        5          5 0.2680611
```

So it seems that the entire lookup table has been merged into the master data, SPARE_COL is surplus to requirements - how can I control what columns get passed into the master data? Essentially, I'm trying to understand how the functionality of an excel vlookup can be used in R.

thanks

Comment: `by='LOOKUP_COL'` controls the join column, is something about this not clear?  The resultant data frame will, by default, contain all the columns on each side of the join.  You can subset this result to drop columns which you don't want.

Comment: results <- merge(df,lookup['COLUMN_A'],by='LOOKUP_COL') is how I've tried to subset the incoming data, but it throws back an error.  The by segment is clear, but the subsetting isn't. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Subset like this: `results <- results[c("col1", "col2", "col3"]`

Comment: ok, i was hoping i could subset within the merge function and not as a separate command - if there is no other way then i'll have to do it as you mention.

Comment: Separation of concerns: merge's job is to do database join stuff on your dataframes, not for other manipulations.

Comment: well, this is exactly what i'm getting it. if i was to write an inner join in SQL, i could decide exactly what fields i want to bring across as part of the join. in R i have to subset / drop them post join. it's not a separation, i'd like to to exactly replicate the join functionality in sql

Comment: R is not a database tool.  Perhaps the closest thing you can get would be the `sqldf` package.

Comment: I would suggest using `data.table` instead of `data.frame` for performance reasons and a lighter syntax. Is `data.frame` a "must have" for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: This one uses SPARE_COL as the one to keep instead of COLUMN_A. If you have columns with the same name in different dataframes, the solution with indices will require that you rename them in one of the data frames before merging everything together.

### Single column

You can do this by passing only the columns you want to merge to the function `merge`. Obviously you have to keep the columns used for merging in your selection. Taking your example, this becomes:

```
keep <- c('LOOKUP_COL','SPARE_COL')
results <- merge(df,lookup[keep],by='LOOKUP_COL')
```

And the result is

```
> results
  LOOKUP_COL COLUMN_A COLUMN_B  SPARE_COL
1          a        1        1 0.75670441
2          b        2        2 0.52122950
3          c        3        3 0.99338019
4          d        4        4 0.71904088
5          e        5        5 0.05405722
```

By selecting the columns first, you make `merge` work faster and you don't have to bother about finding the columns you want after the merge.

If speed is an issue and the merge is simple, you can speed things up by manually doing the merge using indices:

```
id <- match(df$LOOKUP_COL, lookup$LOOKUP_COL)
keep <- c('SPARE_COL')
results <- df
results[keep] <- lookup[id,keep, drop = FALSE]
```

This gives the same result, and gives a good speedup.

### more columns

Let's create an example with 2 lookup columns first:

```
N <- 10000

COLUMN_A <- 1:N
COLUMN_B <- 1:N
LOOKUP_COL <- sample(letters[3:7], N, replace = TRUE)
LOOKUP_2 <- sample(letters[10:14], N, replace = TRUE)

df <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,LOOKUP_COL, LOOKUP_2) 

COLUMN_A <- 2*(1:36)
LOOKUP_COL <- rep(letters[1:6], each = 6)
LOOKUP_2 <- rep(letters[10:15], times = 6)
SPARE_COL <- runif(36)

lookup <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,LOOKUP_COL, LOOKUP_2, SPARE_COL)
```

You can use merge again like this:

```
keep <- c('LOOKUP_COL','SPARE_COL', 'LOOKUP_2')
results <- merge(df,lookup[keep],by=c('LOOKUP_COL', 'LOOKUP_2'))
```

And you can use indices again. Before you match, you have to create the interaction between the lookup columns. You can do this using the function
`interaction()` for any number of lookup columns:

```
  lookups <- c('LOOKUP_COL','LOOKUP_2')
  id <- match(interaction(df[lookups]), 
              interaction(lookup[lookups]))
  keep <- c('SPARE_COL')
  results <- df
  results[keep] <- lookup[id,keep, drop = FALSE]
```

### Timing

In the test below the speedup is about a 6-fold for the two-column case:

```
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
1 code1()          100    6.30    6.117      6.30        0         NA
2 code2()          100    1.03    1.000      1.03        0         NA
  sys.child
1        NA
2        NA
```

The code for testing:

```
N <- 10000

COLUMN_A <- 1:N
COLUMN_B <- 1:N
LOOKUP_COL <- sample(letters[3:7], N, replace = TRUE)
LOOKUP_2 <- sample(letters[10:14], N, replace = TRUE)


df <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,COLUMN_B,LOOKUP_COL, LOOKUP_2) 

COLUMN_A <- 2*(1:36)
LOOKUP_COL <- rep(letters[1:6], each = 6)
LOOKUP_2 <- rep(letters[10:15], times = 6)
SPARE_COL <- runif(36)

lookup <- data.frame(COLUMN_A,LOOKUP_COL, LOOKUP_2, SPARE_COL) 

code1 <- function(){
  keep <- c('LOOKUP_COL','SPARE_COL', 'LOOKUP_2')
  results <- merge(df,lookup[keep],by=c('LOOKUP_COL', 'LOOKUP_2'))
}

code2 <- function(){
  lookups <- c('LOOKUP_COL','LOOKUP_2')
  id <- match(interaction(df[lookups]), 
              interaction(lookup[lookups]))
  keep <- c('SPARE_COL')
  results <- df
  results[keep] <- lookup[id,keep, drop = FALSE]
}

require(rbenchmark)

benchmark(code1(),code2())
```

Comment: hi. thanks for your help here. i'm really interested in your second method using indices, i'm applying this method to c.5m rows of data.  how would that work if my lookup was matching on 2 columns?

Comment: @roastbeeef I added an example for 2 columns, and that can be extended to more. Keep in mind though that you'll need enough memory if you start using either solution on 5 million rows of data.

Answer (score 0):

For manipulating and merging dataframes, I suggest package [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  left_join(lookup, by=c("LOOKUP_COL")) %>%
  select(LOOKUP_COL, COLUMN_A=COLUMN_A.x, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C=COLUMN_A.y)
```

Comment: Especially when using `dplyr`, removing the columns you don't want before the join will give you a huge efficiency gain.